# Unable to view result tree jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, web-api-testing

Hi I am unable to view result tree. Can anyone of you please help me with how can I enable this ?

Last time I did Ctrl+Shift+E since then I am unable to see the tree. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You toggled [Log Viewer window](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) which covers some parts of your Test Elements, you can turn it off by either clicking yellow triangle in upper-right corner of JMeter GUI or from `Options` menu. It's also possible to resize the Log Viewer:

[image]

Also you need to select [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) in the Test Plan.

In general the red number next to the yellow triangle shows that your test has 49 errors so it worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) and see what they're about as most probably they need to be fixed